# Histogram in a table or table.cell

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to change somes plot (line) on histogram.  I can do that, no problem.

```
plot(MC, color=color_bar, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_histogram, title='1')
```

And i want that this histogram is on the bottom of the charts with a small height.
So the idea is to put in a table but, i have the idea but not the knowledge.

I have this code for the table but i don't find information on the web to put a plot in a table.cell

```
//@version=5
indicator("Table test",overlay=true)

var table_hma = table.new(position.bottom_center,10,6,border_width=2,border_color=color.gray, frame_color=color.gray, frame_width=2)
    
table.cell(table_hma, 0, 0, text = "SMA", bgcolor=color.black,text_color=color.white, text_size=size.small)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The text parameter of the table.cell only accepts strings, so you'll have to convert your MC variable into a string

```
//Example
table.cell(table_hma, 0, 0, text = str.trostring(MC, "#"), bgcolor=color.black,text_color=color.white, text_size=size.small)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your help.

I made like this.



var table_hma = table.new(position.bottom_center,10,6,border_width=2,border_color=color.gray, frame_color=color.gray, frame_width=2)
    
table.cell(table_hma, 0, 0, str.tostring(MC_hma_tf, "#"), bgcolor=color.black)

But the histogram is not in the table.  It's as usual on the chart.

Thanks.